# Validation on drop-down value in Angular

Tags: angular, validation, angular10

In Angular, we have to apply validation on 1st drop-down value and once we selected any specific value from drop-down then we can Only select some value from 2nd drop-down

E.g. if we select name from first drop-down then only name from second drop-down you should be able to select and if you select something else in 2nd drop-down then on submitting the form it will show the error message

I have tried using custom validators but I can't make a logic for it to work

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand, you want to match selected items from two different lists, I think you can use Match Password Validator for this, you can find an example from the link.
[Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-match-password-validation?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)